# How to sync specific files only in rsync over ssh?

Tags: linux

I have tried to rsync with this code but I got an error for syntax, please help

```
find /apps/logs -wholename '*server.log*' | rsync -avze ssh --exclude='*/' --files-from=/apps/logs user@0.0.0.0:/data/logs/
```

I want to sync only server.log, but there are several other .log in the directory

Comment: unless `/apps/logs` is a text file that contains the list of files you want to transfer, you are using it wrong. (`e ssh` is the default and unnecessary) If you just want to rsync the server log, the `rsync -uav user@0.0.0.0:/data/logs/server.log /place/you/want/to/put/it`

Comment: ok, i want to send the server.log to remote server, the server.log itself has many different date like, server.log-20018-09-10 and i want to export that to remote server..

Comment: If you want to use the **content** of `server.log` to transfer all files listing within `server.log`, then using `--files-from` has specific syntax requirements. You must provide the *base* or *anchor* path as part of the command.and you will probably want the `--no-R` (`--no-relative`) option as well. The command would look like `rsync -uav --no-R --files-from=/path/to/server.log /xferbase user@0.0.0.0:/xferbase/dest`  By choosing `/xferbase` as `'/'` (the root of the filesystem), your destination is just `user@0.0.0.0:/path/to/dest`

Comment: So to make it all work with `find` you want `find /apps/logs -wholename '*server.log*' > /tmp/filelist`, then `rsync -uav --no-R --files-from=/tmp/filelist / user@0.0.0.0:/path/you/want/the/logs` **Note:** the `'/'` by itself is the `xferbase` and is required.

Comment: thank you sir, i will try your method, but the find /apps/logs -wholename '*server.log*' > /tmp/filelist, what is the > /tmp/filelist use for? sorry newbie

Comment: sir, i have tried ur method but it doesn't send anything, but i modified it. i'm deleting the /tmp/filelist

Comment: Please post the output you are getting when using the options `-uavv` (note the two `v`). This will increase verbosity.

Comment: @David C.Rankin i have updated the screenshoot

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin sir can you help?

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions? Let's remove the temp dir from the equation and use: `find /apps/logs -wholename '*server.log*' > filelist` then `rsync -avze ssh --exclude='*/' --files-from=filelist --no-R ./ user@0.0.0.0:/data/logs/` which will transfer the **files** (excluding directories) found in `/apps/logs` to the new host `0.0.0.0` (which is not real) and store them on that host under `/data/logs` (note: the `./` base since the files in `filelist` will be relative to `./`)

Comment: If you have any additional problems, edit your question and post the contents of `/apps/logs` and a listing of the resulting `filelist`, and confirmation of the connection resulting from `ssh user@0.0.0.0`